# I'm not able to use inline parameter for a specflow scenario in which other steps are reading value from external data source (xlsx)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

```
@DataSource:typeBasedFields.xlsx @DataField:item_type=type

Scenario: Load Item Fields based on the Item Type selected

    Given: the "User A" has logged in

    When: the user selects an <item type>

    Then: the relevant <fields> should be displayed
```

In the above specflow scenario, for the Given step, I'm passing "User A" as the parameter value. At the same time, for the When and Then steps I'm reading the values from the external data source using Specflow External Data plugin.

But when I execute this scenario, item type value read from the external data source is being passed to the Given step instead of the value "User A".

Could someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: Try deleting the .feature.cs file and re-run the test?

Comment: This feels like one of those really wonky issues that require deleting the `.vs` folder in the root of your Visual Studio solution, and deleting all files in the `bin` and `obj` folders of each project.